# exclude field from a nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

to get the information of a user I use a serializer with nested serializers but I have a problem which is that I do not know how to exclude certain fields that are not necessary in this case the user's password, is there any way to exclude that field?

here is the code of the endpoint and the serializers

**endpoint**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@has_permission_decorator('view_team_member')
def getTeamMembers(request, pk):
    try:
        token = decodeJWT(request)
        team_member = TeamMember.objects.filter(pk=pk, company_id=token['company_id'])
        print(team_member)
        serializer = TeamMemberSerializer(team_member, many=True)
        return Response({'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except TeamMember.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'Error': 'Not Found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

**team member serializer**

```
class TeamMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    team = TeamSerializer(read_only=True)
    team_role = TeamRoleSerializer(read_only=True)
    company = CompanySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TeamMember
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ['state', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
        required_fields = ['team', 'user', 'team_role']
```

**user serializer**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    role = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'text'}, write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'text'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'password2', 'company', 'role']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'username': {'required': True},
            'email': {'required': True},
            'first_name': {'required': True},
            'last_name': {'required': True},
            'role': {'required': True},
            'company': {'required': True},
            'password': {'required': True},
            'password2': {'required': True},
        }

    def save(self):
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match'})

        if User.objects.filter(email=self.validated_data['email']).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'Email': 'Email already exists'})

        account = User(email=self.validated_data['email'],
                       company=self.validated_data['company'],
                       first_name=self.validated_data['first_name'],
                       last_name=self.validated_data['last_name'])
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
        user = User.objects.get(id=account.id)
        try:
            assign_role(user, self.validated_data['role'])
        except Exception as e:
            user.delete()
            raise serializers.ValidationError('invalid role')
```

**response**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user": {
                "first_name": "anderson",
                "last_name": "worker",
                "email": "worker@gmail.com",
                "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$320000$CPoWGbsmw7xOKugwP4ygI7$4VpOy9LEDvDCWRHHn/GS6utuT9pYvtOGx+2aP7+IoI0=",
                "company": 1
            },
            "team": {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "frontend-team",
                "state": 1,
                "created_at": "2022-08-01T00:54:05.732842Z",
                "updated_at": null,
                "company": 1
            },
            "team_role": {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "backend-dev",
                "state": 1,
                "created_at": "2022-08-01T00:54:39.197085Z",
                "updated_at": null,
                "company": 1
            },
            "company": {
                "id": 1,
                "description": "infinity tech",
                "state": 1,
                "created_at": "2022-08-01T00:51:31.420658Z",
                "updated_at": null
            },
            "state": 1,
            "created_at": "2022-08-01T01:09:07.457835Z",
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove the password field in the user object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new user serializer to use with `TeamMemberSerializer`.

**user serializer**

```py
class UserSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'company']
```

**team member serializer**

```py
class TeamMemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer2(read_only=True)
    team = TeamSerializer(read_only=True)
    team_role = TeamRoleSerializer(read_only=True)
    company = CompanySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TeamMember
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ['state', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
        required_fields = ['team', 'user', 'team_role']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set the `exclude` attribute in the `UserSerializer`.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        ...
        exclude = ('password',)
    ...
```